# Why do we not get bullet points once we add images in the list items in an unordered list in css?

Tags: html, css

Below is the code I have written. And once I saw the result in the browser, I realized that the bullet points are missing in front of the images I got. But we usually get bullet points when we type text in the 'li' tags of an unordered list.

Why does this happen? And when designing a web page, is it necessary for me to use the `list-style:none` property since bullet points are already not visible? Thank you.

Code:

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="resources/img/1.jpg" alt="Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="resources/img/2.jpg" alt="Simple italian pizza with cherry tomatoes">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="resources/img/3.jpg" alt="Chicken breast steak with vegetables">
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="resources/img/4.jpg" alt="Autumn pumpkin soup">
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I guess it's working fine. I can see the bullets.

Comment: It's working fine to me too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you're not setting `ul` property in your global css file or check if you're using third party css `normalizer`.

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: circle;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://media.nesta.org.uk/images/Predictions-2019_Twitter_02.width-1200.png" alt="Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://media.nesta.org.uk/images/Predictions-2019_Twitter_02.width-1200.png" alt="Simple italian pizza with cherry tomatoes">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://media.nesta.org.uk/images/Predictions-2019_Twitter_02.width-1200.png" alt="Chicken breast steak with vegetables">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="https://media.nesta.org.uk/images/Predictions-2019_Twitter_02.width-1200.png" alt="Autumn pumpkin soup">
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check your CSS or styles if you have over-ridden the default list-style property of the ul > li.

If it is over-ridden, you may add a class (say, diet-list) and write list-style: disc

```css
ul.diet-list > li {
  list-style: disc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="resources/img/1.jpg" alt="Korean bibimbap with egg and vegetables">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="resources/img/2.jpg" alt="Simple italian pizza with cherry tomatoes">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="resources/img/3.jpg" alt="Chicken breast steak with vegetables">
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="resources/img/4.jpg" alt="Autumn pumpkin soup">
    </figure>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have a **css normalizer** in your projet that removes them.
Just add a `list-style-type: disc;` to that particular `ul`.

Comment: Yep! This has exactly been the case! Thank you!!!!!